# Collect 3d Point Cloud from gazebo

Tags: ros, point-clouds

I want to collect a pointcloud of a simulated space in gazebo. I have tried scanning the environment and saving the scans as individual pcd files and then concatenating them but this did not work. I have also tried to take the scans from Gazebo and visualise them in open3d but this ended up just being the same as concatenating the pcd files. I know that the issue is not being able to transform the messages correctly but I have not found a working method with clear steps to execute the transformation. I am doing this on Ros noetic and would really appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [rosbag record](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline) for saving topic data inside ros. This command simply records topic data, saves it to a file, and allows you to analyze or play it back later.

In your situation, you would also need to record the transform topic if you’re having tf issues.

To record data you can simple run a command such as: `rosbag record /tf /my_scan_topic`

Based on your comments what you actually want to do is: first combine multiple scans from the lidar into a single topic; i.e. create a single pointcloud from multiple. The easiest way might be to use the [laser_assembler package](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler). Since this is all in ros the transforms will be handled automatically for you. Then once you have all your scans assembled put it into a PCD file.

Comment: So thats what I did to gather the pointcloud initially and then converted it to PCD. How would I use the TF information? or would it record the tf information and when I concatenate them it will just work?

Comment: @GazzaB it depends on what you mean by use the tf information and what your end goal is. If you’re playing it back for use with some ros node just having the tf topic should be sufficient

Comment: the idea is to construct a complete scan of the room using point clouds gathered from a LiDAR scanner that has been converted to a pointcloud2 message. I would like to have the cloud in a single file or able to built from the directory. Do you think having the TF information available when converting the messages to PCD and then concatenating them will be enough?

Comment: @GazzaB I see. I’ve edited my answer to include what you need to do.